# Is Google Drive's syncing and file indexing faster than Dropbox's?

Tags: sync, dropbox, google-drive

I have both Google Drive and Dropbox installed on my PC. Currently, I am using Dropbox for storing files I would like to access both from home and work PC. 
Because there is a lot of files and folders in Dropbox folder, every time on Windows startup, Dropbox service performs startup file indexing, and it takes around 10 minutes to finish (quite long). During that time PC runs very slow, so basically I have to wait around 15 minutes(after startup) before starting some applications I want to work with.

I guess that Google Drive also performs this startup indexing somehow, so I wonder is it faster than Dropbox? Would PC(Windows) start faster if I move all files from Dropbox to Google Drive?

Comment: Are you expecting better performances at startup with Gdrive instead of DropBox? I guess there is a lot of files to be synced... Why sync these files at startup and have your PC unusable for 15 min.? It's not Gdrive vs DBox but the problem is the wrong way to use it IMHO.

Comment: You need a new hard drive, preferably a SSD.

Comment: How big are the files? How fast is your internet connection?

Comment: @SilverlightFox Well, most of the files are small size, but there is little less than 5 thousands files all together, which takes around 1 GB of memory.

Comment: @SilverlightFox  Internet speed: ~750kb/s download, 80kb/s upload.

Comment: @sunk818 Its a new laptop (and hard disk), not older than one year.

Comment: If you hard drive is 5400rpm or slower then it is too slow to work while Dropbox does its work. Eventually, if you have 4GB of RAM or more, the system will be properly caching for quicker launching of applications. This is why I say you need a new hard drive, preferably a SSD. If you state your exact make and model fo the laptop, and hard drive model if you know it... (see Control Panel > System > Device Manager > Hard Drives), we can tell you definitely.

Comment: @climenole I think you've misunderstood the OP's question. He's not using it wrong.  What he's saying is that start time for the app may be slow.  Your question "Why sync these files at startup and have your PC unusable for 15 min.?" doesn't make sense.  Google Drive and Dropbox index and sync your files after they start - that's the purpose.